# Calculating clusters Entropy, Python

Tags: clustering, python, scikit-learn, k-means, entropy

I ran K-means++ algorithm (Python scikit-learn) to find clusters in my data (containing 5 numeric parameters).
I need to calculate the Entropy. As far as I understood, in order to calculate the entropy,  I need to find the probability of a random single data belonging to each cluster (5 numeric values sums to 1).

How can I find these probabilities? I'm using Python scikit-learn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you are talking about Entropy as an evaluation metric for your clustering.

First, you need to compute the entropy of each cluster. To compute the entropy of a specific cluster, use:
$$ H(i) = -\sum\limits_{j \in K} p(i_{j}) \log_2 p(i_{j})$$

Where $p(i_j)$ is the probability of a point in the cluster $i$ of being classified as class $j$. For instance, if you have $10$ points in cluster $i$ and based on the labels of your true data you have $6$ in class $A$, $3$ in class $B$ and $1$ in class $C$. Then your entropy of cluster $i$ will be:
$$ H(i) = -\left(\frac{6}{10} \log \frac{6}{10} + \frac{3}{10} \log \frac{3}{10} + \frac{1}{10} \log \frac{1}{10}\right)$$

Similarly, you can compute the entropy of other clusters. So first, you need these probabilities of points for each cluster being classified as each class. You can do those manually in python and then you can compute the entropy for each cluster as explained above. Or else once you get the probabilities you can use `scipy.stats.entropy` to compute the entropy of each cluster. Refer to the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.entropy.html) for usage.

Once you have the entropy of each cluster, the overall entropy is just the weighted sum of the entropies of each cluster. You can compute the overall entropy using the following formula:
$$H = \sum\limits_{i \in C} H(i) \frac{N_{i}}{N}$$

where $H$ is the entropy, $N_{i}$ is the number of points in the cluster $i$ and $N$ is the total number of points.